# Salvar valor eu já vem selecionado no combobox

Tags: html, react

Gostaria de salvar com os dados que já vem selecionado mas não funciona, tenho que colocar em sim e depois voltar pro não

Metodo

```
handleChange(e) {
    let obj=Object.assign({},this.state.area)
    obj[e.target.name]=e.target.value
    this.setState({area: obj})
    console.log(obj)
}

<div className="icalcar">
    <select 
        className="combobox" 
        name="calcario" 
        value={this.state.area.calcario} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option name="calcario" value="Não">Não</option>
        <option name="calcario" value="Sim">Sim</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: se tem o componente completo? e o que está tentando fazer? não entendi muito bem

Comment: Não seria porque você está executando a lógica no método `handleChange` e precisa, obrigatoriamente, que o valor tenha mudado para que seja executado? Parece-me o caso de usar a estrutura correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alterar o estado do `select` no momento da seleção o `handleChange` precisa montar novamente a chave correspondente do `calcario`, exemplo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      area: {
        calcario: "Sim"
      }
    }
    this.handleChange =
      this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {    
    const area = {area: { 
      ...this.state.area, 
      calcario: e.target.value 
    }};
    this.setState(area);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>       
        <div style={{height:'25px'}}>
        {this.state.area.calcario}
        </div>
        <select 
          className="combobox" 
          name="calcario" 
          value={this.state.area.calcario} 
          onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```